# Create an SVN user on a Windows server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

I have Subversion, SVN server, running on my Ubuntu server. My production server is a Windows server though.
So I don't want copy and paste my whole project at every release into my Windows server. I just want to do an 'Update' on my Windows server through an SVN user.

When I try to install [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) on Windows Server I get:

> This installation package could not be installed by the windows installer service. You must install a Windows service pack that contains a newer version of the Windows Installer service'

**Question**: Is there any SVN interface (for example like TortoiseSVN), where I can install it on a Windows server?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. TortoiseSVN can be installed on a Windows Server. So what is the question?

Comment: I can't simply install it on a Windows Server, I get 'This installation package could not be installed by the windows installer service' @splash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The Windows server does accept TortoiseSVN. The problem was that the Microsoft® Windows® Installer was not up to date.

According to the TortoiseSVN FAQ:

> This installation package cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service. You must install a Windows service pack that contains a newer version of the Windows Installer service. You need at least version 3 of the msi installer.

In this case, use the link http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483.

Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think if I've understood correctly then all you are looking for is a Subversion client for Windows? I'm hesitant, because you seem to have all the parts of the answer in your question - [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN).

The first line of the description on the website, says it all: "TortoiseSVN is an Apache™ Subversion (SVN)® client, implemented as a Windows shell extension."

With this installed on your windows server you should be able to connect to your Ubuntu hosted Subversion repository and fetch whatever you need.

Comment: I get 'This installation package could not be installed by the windows installer service.You must install a Windows service pack that contains a newer version of the Windows Installer service' when I try to do it @Hargrovm

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have two separate SVN servers which can act as mirrors and have a sync mechanism between them. I found the following blog posts useful for that.

- *[Setting up svnsync-ed (mirrored) SVN repositories on Ubuntu](http://blog.codefront.net/2007/03/29/setting-up-svnsync-ed-mirrored-svn-repositories-on-ubuntu-part-1-of-2/)*
- *[SVN Server on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Web Access](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/svn-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-with-web-access/)*